# How to combine specific SELECT command with UPDATE - SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, command

I need to update the column of some specific tables in my SQL database.

I've got a SELECT command, which selects ALL the right tables but i have no idea how i should combine that with UPDATE (I'm a complete noob).

```
SELECT
  c.id_customer AS id_customer,
  id_gender,
  firstname,
  lastname,
  c.email AS email,
  birthday,
  date_add,
  c.active AS active,
  c.*,
  a.id_group
FROM prstshp_customer_group a
LEFT JOIN prstshp_customer c
  ON (a.id_customer = c.id_customer)
WHERE 1
AND a.id_group = 4
AND c.deleted != 1
AND c.id_shop IN (1)
ORDER BY id_group ASC
```

I have to update the column called `id_default_group` in table `prstshp_customer` with the value "4", of specific entries, selected across the table `prstshp_customer_group` table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `update join`

```
update prstshp_customer
join
(
SELECT
  c.id_customer AS id_customer,
  id_gender,
  firstname,
  lastname,
  c.email AS email,
  birthday,
  date_add,
  c.active AS active,
  a.id_group
FROM prstshp_customer_group a
LEFT JOIN prstshp_customer c
  ON (a.id_customer = c.id_customer)
WHERE 1
AND a.id_group = 4
AND c.deleted != 1
AND c.id_shop IN (1)
)B on prstshp_customer.id_customer=B.id_customer
SET id_default_group=4
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast response!  

I tried that and i get following errors:  

Static analysis:  
3 errors were found during analysis.  
An expression was expected. (near "table" at position 7)  
Unrecognized keyword. (near "table" at position 7)  
Unexpected token. (near "prstshp_customer" at position 13)

Comment: Also tried to remove "table". Then i get  "#1060 - Duplicate column name 'id_customer'"

Comment: I think its the `c.*` in `SELECT` is the reason

Comment: @tcadidot0, yes u r right - i didn't notice it - thank u

Comment: @MarcoBersnak, you can check now

Comment: THANKS, everything worked perfectly :). Your awesome!!